# How do I turn of a Sony VAIO VGN-FW33G Touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, sony-vaio

I have a Sony VGN-FW33G notebook, with **Windows 7 Home Premium x64**.

I want to turn off the touch pad since it gets in the way of typing. Either by using **additional utilities** or disabling it when using a **external mouse**.

**But can't find any drivers for x64.** Currently I am using a Windows touch pad generic hid driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to turn off the touch pad since
>   it gets in the way of typing.

Maybe **[TouchFreeze](http://code.google.com/p/touchfreeze/)** is for you:

Annoyed when you are typing a document and accidentally the palm of your hand brushes the touchpad, changing the position of the cursor in your document or accidentally clicking on an option. TouchFreeze is simple utility for Windows NT/2000/XP that solves this problem. It automatically disables touchpad while you are typing text.

*TouchFreeze is freeware, works for all Windows versions, x86 & x64*

Comment: you're most welcome.